# UICollectionView Custom Layout - Cells are not properly arranged

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

In my iPhone app,I want to use custom lay out in UICollectionview.There will different heights for Collection view cells.I want to set a lay out like that.
I tried many things and at last,made that height adjustment.(I am getting height for each object from server)

But the layout is not in a proper way.There are lots of spaces in between the items.
How can I achieve a proper layout.

Now I am getting a view like this 
[image]

What I want is -

[image]

Here is my code -

```
-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout heightForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
  return 60;
}


 -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   return array.count;   // getting from server
   }


 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   CollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   cell.imageBG.image = [imagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];


   return cell;
   }




  -(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    CGSize retval;


  // I'm taking height of each images into HeightArray

retval =  CGSizeMake(100, [[HeightArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]floatValue ]+50);


return retval;
}
```

Comment: What collection view layout are you using? Have you written your own `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass, or are you using one of the existing ones?

Comment: How can I use that,I am not awaring of that.
Please help me.Would love to know how to use the existing class if there any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshots it seems you are trying to use standard UICollectionViewFlowLayout (or its subclass). Unfortunately its limitation is that each row will always occupy the same height - it will be the same as in highest cell in that row, so you it is not suitable for your task and you have to implement your own layout.

Check [UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout](https://github.com/chiahsien/UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout) class which, although has its limitations (supports only 1 section, no decoration views) provides layout you need and at least can be a good starting point if you won't be able to use it as it is now.

Comment: Thanks vladimir..
Hope I can ask doubts in this if face any :)